# Custom attributes and colors in D3 circle pack

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, colors, circle-pack

I can't do the following:

1: Change the colors of the circles to the color attribute in the json object.

2: On clicking of the a circle get the custom attribute named id from the json object.

I've got the click handler working in the circle node (hello world) but can't get the id attribute.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = {
        "name": "flare",
        "children": [
            { "name": "test1", "size": 20, "color": "#ff0000" , "id": 1},
            { "name": "test2", "size": 40, "color": "#ffff00", "id": 2},
            { "name": "test3", "size": 60, "color": "#ff0000", "id": 3},
            { "name": "test4", "size": 80, "color": "#ff00ff", "id": 4 },
            { "name": "test5", "size": 100, "color": "#0000ff", "id": 5}
        ]
    };

    var r = 960,
        format = d3.format(",d"),
        fill = d3.scale.category20c();

    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
        .sort(null)
        .size([r, r])
        .padding(1.5);

    var vis = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", r)
        .attr("height", r)
        .attr("class", "bubble");

    var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(bubble.nodes(classes(json))
        .filter(function (d) { return !d.children; }))
       .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

    node.append("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
        .on("click", function (d, i) { alert("hello world"); })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return fill(d.packageName); });

    node.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .text(function (d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });

    function classes(root) {
        var classes = [];

        function recurse(name, node) {
            if (node.children)
                node.children.forEach(function (child) {
                    recurse(node.name, child);
                });
            else
                classes.push({
                    packageName: name,
                    className: node.name,
                    value: node.size
                });
         }

         recurse(null, root);
         return { children: classes };
     }

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

The nodes need to contain the color and id from the json object if you want to access them later:

```
if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function (child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
else classes.push({ packageName: name, 
                    className: node.name, 
                    value: node.size, 
                    color: node.color, 
                    id: node.id});
```

Once that data is there, you can use it to alter the actual circles on the screen:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })   
    .style("fill", function (d) { return d.color; })
    .on("click", function (d) { alert("id: " + d.id); });
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, that's worked perfectly. Just started working with D3, the documentation is good but just so much of it to get thro'